# Open arbitrary file using system application picker

Tags: ios, swift, file

I'm working on an iOS app that talks to a service that allows the user to upload arbitrary files. They can then download these files, and they should be able to view them.

I can't find an API that allows me to take a file (either by path, URL, or just raw bytes) and open it. In other apps this kind of operation shows a menu that lets me pick an app to use to view the file. How do I trigger this menu?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is some sort of "document browser" concept. This could work for your needs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/adding_a_document_browser_to_your_app

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

Comment: Document browser/picker is for choosing available documents within and outside app container. But the question states they want to show a menu that can be used to open the file in apps that support such files. UIActivityViewController does exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up being able to do this with [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller). You just give it the URL of a local file and it renders a preview. It can handle a bunch of different file types and comes with a sharing menu out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to provide options to open a file using other apps/services, you can use [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller). You would need to present it as a popover on iPad.

```
let menu = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL], applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(menu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```